# img height "jumps" with width: 100% on site load

Tags: html, css, image

I've a simple but tricky problem. For example the wrapper width is 500px. Inside there is a image with a variable size (larger than the wrapper).

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="1000" height="500" />
</div>
```

So if I set the CSS to this:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
}

.wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The image height "jumps" on site load (only on first load because of the cache). Is there a way to stop that "jumping" without set explicit the image height?

This would be a mobile-friendly site, so I change the wrapper width with `@media` on various screen resolutions so I can't set the image height explicitly.

Comment: Ideally you should [Specify image dimensions](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#SpecifyImageDimensions)

Comment: Hi Philipp. I don't know if you're still having the same problem. I noticed that happening to me today also and found that if your container is smaller than your actual image width/size, it will do that `jumping effect`. Here's what I did: Say my image is made to fit for a 1024x800 screen, I set the CSS to `width:100%`, then I save my image at 1000px by whatever width it will be. `Problem solved`. I can live with the 24px stretch (it will stretch proportionately). Give this a try, cheers.

Comment: So in your case, try this: Save your image at 490px wide, then set the CSS class for `.wrapper img` to `width:100%;` and remove the height attribute while keeping your `width: 500px;` attribute for `.wrapper`. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove the height attribute on the image and remove height from the css as well.

Comment: no. not working. the problem is: if i have a image without width and height attribute, the image is ALWAYS "jumping" on site load. if the image has these attributes, there is no "jumping". and in my case i search a solution for width:100%....

Comment: Remove only the height I'm saying, if you leave the width in it will sort everything out itself.

Comment: no. that is NOT working. on site load (without the image in cache) the image height ist jumping from 0px to xxx px for 50ms or so... that is any browser!

Comment: Well yeah..if it isn't in cache it has to load the images, the wrapper doesn't know the height until it starts loading, pushing stuff around content. unless you specify the height somehow (which changes) then you will get a 'jump'

Comment: yeah that's my problem. the browser should be clever enough, to see the real pixels in the attributes, see the 100% width in CSS and count the exactly new height of image. but i'm probably wrong... :/

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your image in an element with a percentage based padding-bottom. Like so:

`<div style="height: 0px; padding-bottom: X%">`

where `X = Height / Width * 100`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to have image sizes in percent instead of pixels inline.

Comment: yeah... look at my css. width is set to 100%. but i can't set the height to everything because the width of the wrapper is variable.

Comment: no... that is another effect. look here: http://jsfiddle.net/2QVsM/13/ and click multiple times ctrl + r (or whatever in your browser) to reload the cache. do you see the border on site load? :)